# linking clang address sanitizer on FreeBSD 10.1 Release

Tags: c, clang, llvm, freebsd

I'm trying to get address sanitizer working on FreeBSD 10.1 Release, but whenever I try to compile a program with `-fsanitize=address` I get undefined references to `_asan_stack_malloc_1` etc, etc. I found
https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/gcc-clang-address-sanitizer.47985/ on google but the suggestion of adding `-L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include` didn't resolve the linking issue. I tried the llvm binaries for FreeBSD but when I go to compile with that clang I get `/usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.6.0/lib/freebsd/libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.a , no such file or directory.` . Either way I'm not sure what library I need to link or where it is.

Below is the program I tried compiling and here is the command I used,
`clang -fsanitize=address san.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -L /usr/local/lib in your link means that they have compiled a newer version of clang from ports and installed it into /usr/local. Have you done this?

Comment: good point, but `-L/usr/lib` or `-L/lib` doesn't work either.

Comment: what are the output of "which clang" and  "clang --version"?

Comment: `/usr/bin/clang` ` FreeBSD clang version 3.4.1 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot1-final 208032) 20140512`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use asan on FreeBSD you can build llvm with asan support as shown below or you can install from packages/ports like in Kevinoid's answer.

Step one, grab the latest stable llvm source.

```
fetch http://llvm.org/releases/3.9.0/llvm-3.9.0.src.tar.xz
```

Now uncompress the llvm source directory.

```
tar -xvf llvm-3.9.0.src.tar.xz
```

Next change directory to llvm and grab the clang source files.

```
cd llvm-3.9.0.src/tools && fetch http://llvm.org/releases/3.9.0/cfe-3.9.0.src.tar.xz
```

Uncompress clang.

```
tar -xvf cfe-3.9.0.src.tar.xz
```

Enter the projects directory and grab compiler-rt.

```
cd ../projects && fetch http://llvm.org/releases/3.9.0/compiler-rt-3.9.0.src.tar.xz
```

Uncompress compiler-rt.

```
tar -xvf compiler-rt-3.9.0.src.tar.xz
```

Goto the root llvm directory and make a build directory for cmake.

```
cd ../ && mkdir build && cd build
```

Use cmake to setup the llvm build.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON [-DLLVM_ENABLE_WERROR=ON] [-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86] -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ../
```

Build llvm and go grab some tea, it will take a bit.

```
make -j12
```

If the build worked you should be left with clang with asan support. Make sure to remove the old compiler, `/usr/bin/clang`, `/usr/bin/clang++` and `/usr/bin/cc`.
Then install the new clang by doing `sudo make install`. Finally you will probably want to link `/usr/bin/cc` to `/usr/local/bin/clang` by running `sudo ln /usr/local/bin/clang /usr/bin/cc`.

After doing all these steps you should be able to compile code with the `-fsanitize=address` compile option.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to building LLVM, [as suggested in this answer on Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273086), you can install `llvm37` from ports, which supports AddressSanitizer, and build with that:

```
# pkg install llvm37
$ clang37 -fsanitize=address san.c
```